# RestTemplate returns 404 code despite the fact that link is correct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my piece of code:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://stats.quake.com/api/v2/Player/Stats");

builder.queryParam("name", "D&M na1x");

log.info("encoded link: {}", builder.toUriString());

log.info("response: {}", restTemplate.getForObject(
        builder.toUriString(), String.class));
```

and it gives the following output:

```
encoded link: https://stats.quake.com/api/v2/Player/Stats?name=D%26M%20na1x
response: {"code":404,"message":"No results found."}
```

Link is correctly encoded it works in browser and in some rest client (chrome extension). I think there is something wrong with the query parameter (name) because it works for all the other nicks that i have tested (for example `lIlIlIlIlIl` or `myztro RAISY`). My guess is that there is problem with `&` character but URL looks correct. Any ideas whats wrong here? Ofcourse i tried to assign response to object however it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some docs and other users' complaints on SO, it appears that `UriComponentsBuilder` is just encoding the entire URI and not the query param values specifically.

Try doing the encoding yourself: `builder.queryParam("name", URLEncoder.encode("D&M na1x","UTF-8"));`